# Android: Problems with AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob

I added into my app AdMob.

```
 @Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(adView == null)
    {
        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,LabelsShow.AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE);
        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l_eadds);
        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"

              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/l_eadds"
            android:background="@drawable/bgg"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dip" android:background="@drawable/bg_fill">
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp" android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/e"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/search"
                    android:id="@+id/look" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:minWidth="100dip" android:background="@drawable/btn_no"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp" android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:layout_below="@+id/look">
        <requestFocus />
            </WebView>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E"
            android:id="@+id/textViewik" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="19dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In two words: in Android 4+ admob in my app works. But in Android 2.3 doesn't work.
I tested it in 4 phones. Two 4+ and two 2.3.
In 2.3 Activity without banner(
In other apps admob works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a different strategy.

In xml:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:adSize="BANNER"
app:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

and in java class:

> 

```
package com.example.packagename;

     import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
     import com.google.ads.AdView;


     import android.os.Handler;

     public class ClassName extends Activity {

        private AdRequest re;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            final AdView adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            re = new AdRequest();
            adview.loadAd(re);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    re = new AdRequest();

                    adview.loadAd(re);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 15000);
                }
            }, 15000);

            --rest of code
        }
```

Hope you can use this.